# FQL to Find who all(uid) of MY FRIENDS are tagged in a photo with pid=N?

Tags: facebook-fql

I need to find out who all(my friends only) are tagged in a specific photo. I know the pid of the photo. This needs to be done via a FQL query.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This will give you most of the data you should need about a friend tagged in a specific photo.

```
SELECT id, name, pic_square, username, type FROM profile WHERE id IN
  (SELECT subject FROM photo_tag WHERE pid = XXXXX AND subject IN
    (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ) )
```

You may not get all your friends with this query who are visible in the Facebook app. This depends on how they have their privacy settings configured. The API won't return their data to you if their privacy isn't set to public.

Depending on how you're getting it, you may want to sub out `object_id` for `pid`. The `pid` field seems like it's on the path to deprecation.